# Geometry with right triangles

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I have this

[image]

How do I find $h$? I know that I must use the cosine of $70$ degrees but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Is it a sector? Is the triangle a right triangle?

Comment: yes there is a right triangel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a sector, then we know that the length of the hypotenuse of the right triangle is $L$, so we have
$$h=L\cos70^\circ.$$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Comment: Could you draw me some quick image... Im not sure how to interpret it myself to be honest

Comment: @Astroman: Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If the center of the arc is in the right angle you have:
$$
\dfrac{L-h}{h}=\tan 70°
$$

that we you can solve for $h$.

If the center of the arc is in the $70°$ angle you have:
$$
h=L\cos 70°
$$
because the right triangle has hypotenuse $L$ and $h$ is the adiacent side to angle of $70°$.

Comment: Here is the answer that it gives h=cos x * L

Comment: So, I've not well interpreted the figure. I change the ansewer :)

Comment: Sorry but could you draw me a picture... I dont understand